# How to programmatically get thumbnail of a product?

Tags: magento2, product, catalog, media, gallery

```
$product = $this->productFactory->create()->load($productId);


$existingMediaGalleryEntries = $product->getMediaGallery()['images'];

foreach ($existingMediaGalleryEntries as $key => $entry) {
    //$entry does not contain the information I need
}
```

How do I get an thumbnail/small/base- image of product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$existingMediaGalleryEntries = $product->getMediaGalleryEntries();

foreach ($existingMediaGalleryEntries as $entry) {
    $entry->getTypes();
}
```

`getTypes()` returns an array that may contain the following vlaues:

- image
- small_image
- thumbnail

if it contains `thumbnail` it's the thumbnail image

Comment: How can you get image src by this function ????????

Comment: $entry->getFile(); should do it

Comment: @PhilippSander getFile() only return the relative file path, is there another way to get the absolute file path?

Comment: Do you know how to also programatically set the image type without replacing the image? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/287936/magento-2-3-2-set-product-image-role-per-store-view